# discord.py how can I get information view is interacted?

Tags: discord.py

```
from discord import ui, app_commands, Interaction
import discord
import asyncio

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        await tree.sync()
        print(f"{self.user} on")

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="auction", description="auction")
async def auction(interaction:Interaction):
    auction_interaction=interaction
    async def up_callback(interaction:Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("message", ephemeral=True)
        await auction_callback(interaction)
    async def auction_callback(interaction:Interaction):
        view = ui.View()
        up_button = ui.Button(label="up")
        view.add_item(up_button)
        up_button.callback=up_callback
        await auction_interaction.edit_original_response(view=view)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        if view.is_finished(): # here
            return
        else:
            await auction_interaction.delete_original_response() # end
            
    await interaction.response.send_message("Welcome to my auction")

client.run(token)
```

I wanna get the user clicked button information in auction_callback function.

I thought view.is_finished() is True when I clicked button, but isn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A [View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#view) is only finished when it reaches the timeout or the `View.stop()` method is called. You haven't set a timeout for your view or stopped it. Therefore, it will never be finished. Observing your code, I notice a big confusion and I'll show you the best way to work with views using `discord.py`: inheriting classes.

```py
class AuctionView(ui.View):

    # This decorator creates a button links it to the callback below
    # and adds it to the view
    @discord.ui.button(label="up")
    async def up(interaction: Interaction, button: ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hi {interaction.user}", ephemeral=True)
        self.stop()

@tree.command(name="auction", description="auction")
async def auction(interaction: Interaction):
    view = ActionView(timeout=10)
    await interaction.response.send_message("Welcome to my auction", view=view)
    await view.wait()  # wait until the view is finished
    # do something
```